# How to show a display value for selected node in treeview in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, treeview

I am trying to create a treeview which pulls info from a sql database. I want the text to be the name field but when you double click the name i want it to display the id field. I have look and looked but cant find any info on this?

Code tried (Added from OP's comment):

```
   foreach (DataRow dr in Db.Table("Employee").Rows) 
   { 
      treeView1.Nodes.Add(
             new TreeNode(dr["Name"].ToString(),
             new TreeNode[] {new TreeNode(dr["EEID"].ToString())}));
   } 
      var node = treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes[0].Text; 
      MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You selected: {0}", node));
```

Comment: foreach (DataRow dr in Db.Table("Employee").Rows)
            {                
             treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(dr["Name"].ToString(),new TreeNode[] {new TreeNode(dr["EEID"].ToString())}));
            }            var node = treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes[0].Text;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You selected: {0}", node));

Comment: sorry for the mess, but i get error when i copy paste code here...its not as user friendly as it can be i guess.

Comment: Its okay I added it to the question.

Comment: thats pretty good... LOL thanks.

Comment: just a heads up: generally you don't want to edit the answer to your question into the question. If you figured it out yourself, just do what you did: give the answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in Db.Table("Employee").Rows)
{ 
  TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(); 
  tn.Tag = dr["eeid"]; 
  tn.Text = dr["Name"].ToString(); 
  treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn); 
} 
private void treeView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  MessageBox.Show(treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: here is my answer. thanks for all the help. it was the infamous tag that held me up...not sure why they didn't just give it a display value property like the list box but hey it works.

Answer (score 5):

When you create new nodes for a TreeView you can specify a text value and a key value, like so:

```
TreeView tv = new TreeView();
tv.Nodes.Add(key, text); //where key is your database id value, and text the display
```

Then you'd simply return the key of the clicked node. Is this what you want?

**EDIT:** This is what happens when you speak from memory... this is **wrong**. 'key' is not a hidden key value, like an ID, 'key' is the name of the tree node. Please hold while I give you a proper solution.

** EDIT2 (SOLVED) ** : You can also use the Name property. Like this:

```
tView.Nodes.Add("Id_0001", "Mr. Dexter");
```

then you could retrieve the values of that node with something like this:

```
    private void tvView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = e.Node;
        MessageBox.Show(node.Name + "\n" + node.Text);
    }
```

which would yield the results: "Id_0001" and "Mr. Dexter".

Comment: I think this is close but im not sure how to call the ID.
var node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
I would like something like this if possible:
var node = treeView1.DisplayValue; or whatever. I hope that help you help me... : )

Comment: No, if you do `var node = treeView1.SelectedNode` _node_ gets instanced as a TreeViewNode object. So, you can then print its display value and its key (hidden) value. Sorry can't provide you with the exact wording, I don't have a VS on this machine and my memory has no Intellisense...

Answer (score 1):

you can use Mouse Click event. when you click on a particular node (assume it's not WPF cause then it's Items) you can get its Text from SelectedNode property.

```
 private void btnGetNodeValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nodeVal=  treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;

        }
```

then you can pass this string value to database to retrieve your value,mix up with Select statement and WHERE clause so you can easily get it.

Comment: yes but i want to double click on the name and display the ID or diff value other than the name which is selectednode.text. im looking for something like selectedvalue.text if possible.